# linux date validation difference between ubuntu and centos

Tags: linux, shell, date, ubuntu

The following works on my Ubuntu machine

> $ date -d 2014-07-23T00:00Z
>
> ons 23 jul 2014 02:00:00 CEST

While on another machine running centos I get

> $ date -d 2014-07-23T00:00Z
>
> date: invalid date `2014-07-23T00:00Z'

From running

> date --version

I can see that the version of gnu coreutils are  8.21 on Ubuntu and 8.4 on the centos machine.

My question is this: Is it due to differences in date functionality that this happens, or does it have to do with somehing else (like the locale, which I have played with a bit without success)?

If it is due to differences in date functionality, where can I read about these updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`NEWS` file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS):

```
* Noteworthy changes in release 8.13 (2011-09-08) [stable]

[..trim..]

** New features

  date now accepts ISO 8601 date-time strings with "T" as the
  separator.  It has long parsed dates like "2004-02-29 16:21:42"
  with a space between the date and time strings.  Now it also parses
  "2004-02-29T16:21:42" and fractional-second and time-zone-annotated
  variants like "2004-02-29T16:21:42.333-07:00"
```

So, it's a feature available in GNU Coreutils 8.13 and newer.

This entry should also give you an answer on how to fix your string so that it works for both platforms :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I hadn't found that news file. I tried the changelog under /usr/share/doc/coreutils but didn't find this golden nugget.